# adding a newly created and uploaded package to pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-packaging

1. I created a package (thompcoUtils) on test.pypi.org and pypi.org
2. https://pypi.org/project/thompcoUtils/ and https://test.pypi.org/project/thompcoUtils/ show the package is installed in both the test and live repositories
3. I added the repositories https://test.pypi.org/simple/ and https://pypi.org/simple/ to pycharm.
4. I refreshed and searched for the package in pycharm under available packages but thompcoUtils could not be found.
5. I am using virtual environments in pycharm

I am able to install the package with both

```
pip install thompcoUtils
```

and

```
pip3 install thompcoUtils
```

Any suggestions would be most helpful!

When I search for the package, its not there:
[image]

BUT, I know its there because I can edit it:
[image]

I tried this:

```
twine upload dist/*
```

and now I can install from pip3 correctly (when I update the package version and then upload it, the package is correctly downloaded and installed) but, I still cannot import it in my python3 script

Comment: I just figured out why pip is working...

pip3 install --no-cache-dir  thompcoUtils
Collecting thompcoUtils
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/4e/bf13bae930cd77343b41a5f5b1f53fe1d602235ee610a66f31062adbf0b5/thompcoUtils-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Its coming from the wrong repository!  Back to square one...

Answer (score 0):

This question is better asked in a [different way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081954/created-package-but-cannot-use-it-from-pypi) so I am answering it and closing it out.